# Provision Chef using Packer on local machine

Tags: chef-infra, packer, packer-builder, hashicorp-packer

I'm new to Chef/Packer so apologies if this is a novice question, basically I'm trying to get Packer to use my local machine to build the image and execute a shell script. Following is my packer-build.json

```
{
  "builders": [
    {
      "type": "file",
      "name": "example",
      "target": "./test_artifact.txt",
      "content": "example content"
    }
  ],
  "provisioners": [
    {
      "type": "chef-solo",
      "cookbook_paths": ["/Users/bakthak/code/nc_deployment/chef-repo/cookbooks"],
      "staging_directory": "/Users/bakthak",
      "execute_command": "sh /Users/bakthak/check.sh"
    }
  ]
}
```

Running build with this file produces the output

```
==> example: Provisioning with chef-solo
    example: Installing Chef...
    example: Creating directory: /Users/bakthak
    example: Creating directory: /Users/bakthak/cookbooks-0
    example: Creating configuration file 'solo.rb'
    example: Creating JSON attribute file
    example: Executing Chef: sh /Users/bakthak/check.sh
Build 'example' finished.
```

I had a few questions about this:

1. Is packer using my local machine to install chef and build the image?
2. Looks like the shell script `sh /Users/bakthak/check.sh` is not executed since that script creates a bunch of files in a directory which does not exist after packer build completion.

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Packer will connect and run the "provisioner" on the machine/target identified or created in `"builders":` section. As per the documentation on the `file` builder:

> The `file` Packer builder is not really a builder, it just creates an artifact from a file. It can be used to debug post-processors without incurring high wait times.

So by using this builder, you are not creating a connection to anywhere. However there is a builder called `null` which can be used establish an SSH session and run the provisioner.

Consider the example below where `192.168.1.102` is the IP address of my machine (localhost on which `packer` is running), with the credentials that can SSH to it:

```json
{
  "builders": [
    {
      "type": "null",
      "ssh_host": "192.168.1.102",
      "ssh_username": "user1",
      "ssh_password": "changeit"
    }
  ],
  "provisioners": [
    {
      "type": "chef-solo",
      "cookbook_paths": ["/home/user1/.chef/cookbooks"],
      "run_list": "my_cookbook",
      "execute_command": "sh /home/user1/myscript.sh"
    }
  ]
}
```

That said, it would be better to stick to the default `execute_command`, for the `chef-solo` provisioner:

```
chef-solo --no-color -c <ConfigPath> -j <.JsonPath>
```

and run the script from a Chef resource:

*my_cookbook/recipes/default.rb*:

```ruby
script 'myscript.sh' do
  interpreter 'bash'
  cwd '/home/user1/'
  code <<-EOH
    # Content of the script as
    # some shell commands
  EOH
end
```